# Custom CSS to SliderExtender in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css, slider, jquery-ui-slider, sliderextender

I'm building web app using `asp.net web forms` and i have a `SliderExtender` in a `TemplateField` of a `Grid View` as below.

```
<ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtbox_count"
    BoundControlID="txtbox_count_BoundControl" Orientation="Horizontal" EnableHandleAnimation="true"
    RailCssClass="SliderRail" HandleCssClass="SliderHandle" HandleImageUrl="~/Images/slider_h_handle.gif"
    Minimum="0" Maximum='<%# double.Parse(Eval("VEHICLE_TYPE.MAX_AMOUNT").ToString()) %>'>
</ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbox_count" Width="25" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VEHICLE_AVAILABILITY.EXIST_COUNT") %>'
    Style="text-align: right"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbox_count_BoundControl" Width="25" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VEHICLE_AVAILABILITY.EXIST_COUNT") %>'
    Style="text-align: right"></asp:TextBox>
```

**CSS of RailCssClass and HandleCssClass**

```
.SliderHandle
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 22px;
    width: 10px;
}
.SliderRail
{
    position: relative;
    background: url('../../Images/slider_h_rail.gif') repeat-x;
    height: 22px;
    width: 125px;
}
```

This looks like below.

[image: default slider]

But I need to customize the slider like below.

[image: Slider - jQuery UI]

How can I do this? What should I change in my `css` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have created example 
Download sample from http://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.10.3.zip

include all necessory resource like jquery, CSS, images etc from demo into your project

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestSf.WebForm2" %>

    <%@ Register Src="SliderControl.ascx" TagName="SliderControl" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grd" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MaxValue" HeaderText="MaxValue" SortExpression="MaxValue" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Slider">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <uc1:SliderControl ID="SliderControl1" runat="server" ctrlID='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                            Maxvalue='<%# Eval("MaxValue") %>' Value='<%# Eval("Value") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         if(arr.indexOf($(this).val())>-1)
          {
                alert('This is already selected , please select other option');
                return false;
          }
        </script>
    </asp:Content>
```

c# Sample code

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<TestMax> lst = new List<TestMax>();
            lst.Add(new TestMax() { ID = 1, MaxValue = 10, Value = 4, Name = "Sandeep" });
            lst.Add(new TestMax() { ID = 2, MaxValue = 12, Value = 3, Name = "Nilesh" });
            lst.Add(new TestMax() { ID = 3, MaxValue = 11, Value = 6, Name = "Jayesh" });
            grd.DataSource = lst;
            grd.DataBind();
        }
    }
    public class TestMax
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int MaxValue { get; set; }

        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Create a new USerControl and use this markup

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SliderControl.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="TestSf.SliderControl" %>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#slider-range-max<%= ctrlID %>").slider({ range: "max", min: 1, max: <%= Maxvalue %>,
            value: <%= Value %>, slide: function (event, ui) { $("#amount<%= ctrlID %>").val(ui.value); } 
        });
        $("#amount<%= ctrlID %>").val($("#slider-range-max<%= ctrlID %>").slider("value"));
    });
</script>
<div id="slider-range-max<%= ctrlID %>">
</div>
<input type="text" id="amount<%= ctrlID %>" style="border: 2; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
```

UserControl C# code

```
 public partial class SliderControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public int ctrlID { get; set; }
        public int Maxvalue { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. What is `uc1:SliderControl` ? `uc1` means ? if have `.net` project which you have created for this, can you please upload to some file sharing site and comment link here.

Comment: I have updated first Code block which contains GridView. uc1 is reference Tagname for usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply styles using the following properties.

```
RailCssClass="ajax__slider_h_rail"

HandleCssClass="ajax__slider_h_handle"
```

and their styles as follows, which you can edit according to your requirements.

```
.ajax__slider_h_rail 
{
    position:relative;
    height:20px;

}
.ajax__slider_h_handle 
{

position:absolute;
    height:20px;width:10px;

}
.ajax__slider_v_rail 
{

position:relative;
    width:20px;

}
.ajax__slider_v_handle 
{

position:absolute;
    height:10px;width:20px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, You are using [AjaxControlToolkit slider](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/Slider/Slider.aspx) while, expecting UI as [jquery slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/).
if you can switch the control, it will solve your issue. 
otherwise,
put these css classes

```
.ajax__slider_h_rail {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    height: 8px;
    position: relative;
}
.ajax__slider_h_handle {
    height: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px !important;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to add `jquery slider`. but i need to show slider on `gridview`. i need to set `max` of slider from value in database. in `AjaxControlToolkit slider`, i set it by `Maximum='<%# double.Parse(Eval("VEHICLE_TYPE.MAX_AMOUNT").ToString()) %>'`. but i have no idea about how to set max value when using jquery slider. because max value is different in each gridview row.

Comment: try this http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemax , it demonstrates min/max values. Again, jquery is purely javascript based, so you might have to change your implementation. or did you try the CSS classes I provided ? put the Classes into your page, you will get nearer result.

Comment: I tried the `CSS` classes you have provided. but `AjaxControlToolkit slider` is good for me than it. :) assume there are 3 rows in grid view. so there are 3 sliders. i need to set 3 values for max value of these three sliders.

Answer (score 0):

First use following code to stop showing the default image

```css
.handleStyle img
{
    display:none;
}
```

Then use whatever styles you are using for handle like following

```css
.handleStyle
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    background-color:Red;
    border-radius:8px;
}
```